# Spark Structured Streaming with Kafka version 2

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

We updated our kafka version to 2.0 from 0.9

Need help in finding the right client library for spark structured streaming

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10" % "2.3.0"
```

doesnt work.

This is the error it throws:

`11:46:18.061 [stream execution thread for [id = e393ea37-8009-4ce0-b996-94f767994fb8, runId = bc15eb7d-876d-4e01-8ee5-22205ec7fdcb]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-8ce7f26f-e342-4b0d-85f1-a9f641b79629-1052905425-driver-0] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
11:46:18.061 [stream execution thread for [id = e393ea37-8009-4ce0-b996-94f767994fb8, runId = bc15eb7d-876d-4e01-8ee5-22205ec7fdcb]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-8ce7f26f-e342-4b0d-85f1-a9f641b79629-1052905425-driver-0] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
11:46:18.452 [stream execution thread for [id = e393ea37-8009-4ce0-b996-94f767994fb8, runId = bc15eb7d-876d-4e01-8ee5-22205ec7fdcb]] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector - [Consumer clientId=consumer-2, groupId=spark-kafka-source-8ce7f26f-e342-4b0d-85f1-a9f641b79629-1052905425-driver-0] Connection with kafka-muhammad-45e0.aivencloud.com/18.203.67.147 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:119)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:335)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:296)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead(Selector.java:560)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please provide more information (how about errors?!). Kafka brokers are engineered to be backwards compatible, this helps with projects that lag significantly behind the latest APIs (like Spark).

The artifactId you're referencing `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10` is for [Spark Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-integration.html), in order to use [Spark Structured Streaming](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html) you'll want to use `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11`

Comment: Added the logs.
Also, I am using both `spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11` and `spark-streaming-kafka-0-10`
Looking for a library that supports kafka2.0

Comment: Like I said, Kafka 2.0 can be used as the brokers for the Spark libraries you're specifying. The EOF error you paste looks like the Kafka broker closing your connection after a period of idle. I can't really help more unless you provide the code that generates that error.

Comment: No worries Chris, I wasn't passing the ssl properties correctly. The ssl, truststore properties have to be prefixed by `kafka.` I was initially using "ssl.truststore.location" instead of "kafka.ssl.truststore.location"